# ASP.NET Web API tries to serve physical directories instead of mapped controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express

I have an existing ASP.NET Web API 2 project that was previously served under route prefix `/api/` (`example.com/api/Users`), but now it needs to be moved directly under the root (`example.com/Users`).

The problem is that now some of the routes match physical directories in the project root, and IIS tries to serve those directories when making such conflicting request.

This is what the project structure looks like:

```
MyApi/
  App_Start/
  Controllers/
  Models/
  ...
  Permissions/
  ...
  Global.asax
  Global.asax.cs
  ...
  Web.config
```

The routes are mapped using attribute routes: `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

And here's a simplified sample of a problematic controller:

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Permissions")]
    public class PermissionController
    {
        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Permission>))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return ...
```

When a request is made to `example.com/Permissions`, IIS first responds with a `301` redirect to `example.com/Permissions/` (trailing slash) and then with:

```
IIS 10.0 Detailed Error
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Detailed Error Information:
Module           DirectoryListingModule
Notification     ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler          StaticFile
Error Code       0x00000000
```

All other controllers without conflicting directory names work as expected.

I've tried both enabling and disabling `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`, I've tried adding and removing handlers like this:

```
<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

And I've even tried removing the `StaticFile` handler, but nothing I've tried so far has worked.

This is the `Web.config` currectly. It is identical to what Visual Studio 2015 generates by default when creating a new empty Web API 2 project:

```
...
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
...
```

So can I prevent IIS from trying to serve physical files inside the project? The API should only serve dynamically generated content from the controllers.

Comment: A similar problem to which the solution also applies: ASP.NET Web API 2 does require a virtual directory on "/" mapped to the physical root of the App for working at all. However, http handlers do trap and try to serve as a static file any URL whose last path element ends in ".something" (i.e. a dot followed by any extension), meaning that any Web API route like /someApp/{aContext}/{aResource} mapped to a GET will yield an HTTP 404 error whenever the {aResource} contains a dot, whereas "GET .../someApp/aContext/xxxx.yyyy/" with a trailing slash will correctly hit the API !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I seem to have found the solution.

This flag makes the API prefer the controller instead of the directory:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Changes for `Web.config`:

- `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` allows dots in the URL (`/Users/firstname.lastmane`)
- Removing the `StaticFile` handler will return `404` errors instead of `403` erros for physical directories which don't match any mapped routes.

Content:

```
...
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="StaticFile" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
...
```

Comment: I'm unable to get CORS to add headers to routes that have dots in the last token of the url like this. SO FRUSTRATING.